# Sublime Text 2 fails to build: `Unable to find target command: compiler`

Tags: latex, sublimetext2, sublime-text-plugin

I'm having difficulty building documents with LaTeXing.

When I build(via any build system using `cmd-B` or UI) the console returns:

```
Unable to find target command: compiler
```

I have:

- restarted ST
- uninstalled and reinstalled LaTeXing
- restarted computer

Versions: `OSX 10.13.2, ST 2.0.2 Build 2221`

Comment: When you say `any build system` do you mean literally any build system (e.g. Python) or just any of the `LaTeXing` builds?

Comment: @OdaNurd It was every build system. I actually just upgraded to ST3

Comment: Your problem might have been related to your version of MacOS; ST2 depends on a system installed version of Python and the version that Apple ships changed in a recent-ish MacOS build, which breaks ST2 in various ways.

Comment: @OdatNurd I see; I looked around _a lot_ for reference to my issue but couldn't find it :/ Any links to fixes?

Comment: For ST2 not that I'm aware of; it's not officially supported any longer and has been superseded by ST3.

Comment: @OdatNurd alright, I suppose this question can be closed?

Comment: It's possible someone might be able to answer it, but at the moment it's more or less academic, I think.